# Type or Namespace Name "AspNetCore" does not exist error when publishing to Azure

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-2.1

In Visual Studio 2017, I build my ASP.NET Core 2.1 app with no errors but when I try to publish it to Azure, I get errors that indicate I'm missing a reference to an assembly -- see below:
[image]

But I'm **not** missing a reference and where these errors point, the reference is there with no errors whatsoever.

More importantly, this is happening **ONLY IF** I target a runtime other than "Portable" in my publish profile. If I select "Portable" for target runtime and leave it at "Framework dependent" in deployment mode (see below), I can publish to Azure or into a folder just fine.
[image]

Any idea how to fix this issue? I've seen a few similar posts here and they suggest I do `dotnet restore` which didn't help.

I'd appreciate some suggestions here as this is now becoming a pretty major obstacle for me.

Because I'm trying to work with ASP.NET Core 2.1 Preview-2, I do need to select x64 as the target runtime so that my settings match what's installed on Azure. If I select x64, I can't publish. If I publish it with "Portable" setting, Azure App service gives me an error. See my other post on that here: [ASP.NET Core 2.1 Preview 2 App Not working on Azure App Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49787507/asp-net-core-2-1-preview-2-app-not-working-on-azure-app-service)

I'd really appreciate some help here as I seem to be completely stuck!

Comment: What happens if you instead try to publish to a local folder? If you get the same errors (which is my guess), then at least Azure is completely out of the equation.

Comment: Same error. If I run it locally, however, everything is fine. I think I started having these issues ever since I installed the update to the SDK to upgrade my app to ASP.NET Core 2.1 Preview-2. I just can't seem to publish my app anymore.

Comment: I suggest changing the title and tags to avoid confusion. This is a pure Core publishing question, unrelated to Azure.

Comment: I just installed VS 2017 Preview 4, installed Net Core 2.1.300 preview 2, and was able to successfully deploy to an Azure app service with x64 config.

Comment: I'm running VS 15.7.0 Preview 4 and have the SDK upgraded .Still having the same problem.

Comment: Not sure if this makes sense, but see if https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/6516#issuecomment-352748339 of any help?

Comment: @Sam, can you try deploying this basic app? https://github.com/miparnisari/AspNetCore2.1 - also, this is my publish profile, maybe you can spot a difference: https://gist.github.com/miparnisari/beeadab9ae62914d8eb522618043efe8

Comment: Perhaps post your project file and your packages.json file, perhaps something in there is strange, for instance this reference set only for a specific platform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This mystery never got resolved but upgrading to the latest stable version of Visual Studio 2017 15.7.1 seems to fix the problem.